# Can /t/ get assimilated to /ʃ/?

Tags: assimilation

The word "sort of" gets pronounced as something like "so shav" or "so sha" in the below video

https://youtu.be/uCcFSUWNoDw?t=46

Is this common? If so, what are the rules for such assimilation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/t/ can assimilate to /ʃ/, i.e. /tʃ/ can become [ʃʃ]. However, what is happening in that video is something totally different. This is known as "lenition", a feature of some dialects (on the rise in RP), where /t/ becomes an affricate. Thus, [sɔtsʌv]. This seems to be very common in Liverpool. Other of his videos don't suggest that he does this systematically, but some people do. It's a sociolinguistic problem – who does it, and when do they do it?

Comment: seconding that Liverpool has quite widespread lenition of voiceless stops, typically to (various) fricatives, in certain positions. This may be due to Irish influence